# What's the 3-dots method argument in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain me this syntax:

```
def hello(...)
  p(...).to_a
end

hello 1,2,3,4 # => [1,2,3,4]
```

What is type of `...` ?

Comment: @meagar actually it's not a syntax error for ruby 3.

Comment: @AlexGolubenko And Ruby 2.7.1 apparently, though I can't find anything about in the release notes for [2.7.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/25/ruby-2-7-0-released/) or [2.7.1](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2020/03/31/ruby-2-7-1-released/), though it's described here: https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/12/04/ruby-2-7-adds-new-operator-for-arguments-forwarding.html

Comment: @meagar yeah, you are right :)

Comment: What do you mean by "What is type of `...` ?" Ruby is an untyped language (or dynamically typed, or uni-typed, depending on who you ask), it doesn't have types. And even in statically typed languages, syntax elements typically don't have types, only expressions and identifiers do.

Comment: @meagar: Not every single little feature is explicitly called out in the release notes, but the release notes *always* contain a link to the NEWS file (quote: "See NEWS or commit logs for more details."), and the `...` argument forwarding feature *is* documented [there](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_7_0/NEWS#label-Other+miscellaneous+changes).

Comment: @JörgWMittag a completely new syntax seems worthy of calliing out to me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is called *argument forwarding*. It is similar to how `super` without argument list works (i.e. forward all arguments to the `super` method), but for arbitrary method delegation.

So, in this case it means "Accept arbitrary arguments and forward them to `p`".

It was added in Ruby 2.7.0. Documentation is somewhat sparse at the moment, it is only documented in

- [the `NEWS` file](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_7_0/NEWS#label-Other+miscellaneous+changes) accompanying the Ruby 2.7.0 release and
- [Feature request #16253 *Shorthand "forward everything" syntax*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16253).

Answer (score 26):

I think [this](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/12/04/ruby-2-7-adds-new-operator-for-arguments-forwarding.html) article will help you to understand it better.
In short, this is a new "shorthand syntax" for leading arguments to make code a bit "easier", now instead of `call(*args, **kws, &block)` you can just write `call(...)`

Here is a simple example:

```rb
def perform(*args, **kws, &block)
  block.call(args, kws)
end

def call(...)
  perform(...)
end

> call(1, 2, 3, k1: 4, k2: 5) {|*x| puts x}
1
2
3
{:k1=>4, :k2=>5}
```